# What is an easy way to drain a laptop battery to 0?

Tags: linux, battery

I need a way to kill my battery in my Ubuntu laptop. Is there any mind numbing tasks I can Ubuntu do that will eat up the battery? I have already shut off the power management options.

The battery is giving my issues and and someone said I should discharge it fully an recharge it from 0.

Comment: As an aside, it is possible that this someone has no idea what they are talking about. You can't really "reboot" a battery, and while I'm no HW expert, discharging a battery to 0 sound kind of unhealthy for it, to be frank.

Comment: @Williham is correct. Laptop batteries should never be brought below approximately 40% charge. It's very bad for them. Some people say you can have a complete discharge cycle every 100-300 charge cycles, though.

Comment: @Reid: Surely that's *can*, and not *should*?

Comment: Well the battery is not working correctly to begin with, so fully discharging it and recharging it can't do anymore harm than has been done by the previous owner.

Comment: Something is messed up with the battery, it charged 25% is 5 mins.

Comment: Is there anything speaking against leaving it turned on and just waiting for it to die?

Comment: @Williham: Ah, yes, I meant *should* instead of *can*. :P

Comment: I've heard of this related to "recalibrating" the battery.  E.g., http://www.tech-no-media.com/2009/07/how-to-extend-lithium-ion-laptop.html

Comment: Here's another interesting article on Li-Ion life: http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/how_to_prolong_lithium_based_batteries - the takeaway is pretty much 1. battery life will degrade over time and 2. " Partial discharge on Li-ion is fine; there is no memory and the battery does not need periodic full discharge cycles other than to calibrate the fuel gauge on a smart battery"

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`apt-get install stress` - a utility specifically designed for testing CPU and other functions.  You can use it to peg your CPU at 100% usage until the battery dies.

I'm not sure what options exist to peg GPU usage at 100%.

You should drop to runlevel 1 and dismount all volumes possible since your system will not shutdown smoothly.

Comment: Another option would be to use a livecd such as http://www.stresslinux.org/

Comment: i like the idea of a live cd because the machine will just stop and wont hurt the drives.

Comment: I could not get the stresslinux to start on the laptop, so I just ran memtest 86+. That worked fine, I am interested in trying out that stress linux though. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Simply run:

```
while :; do :; done
```

In a terminal.  That is an infinite do-nothing loop that will increase CPU usage to ~100% for one core.  You could repeat this 4 times in parallel if you have a quad-core processor, but on the few laptops I've tested this on, it hasn't increased battery drain.

In addition:  Increase screen brightness to full, blast music at max volume, ensure WiFi is on, and plug in as many power draining USB devices as you can:  Phones, hard drives, etc.

This should kill most laptops in under 2 hours.

Comment: I received syntax error

Comment: $ while :; do done
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `done'

Comment: @user: Thank you. Fixed

Answer (score 3):

Run lots of Virtual Machines

Do a full `ls -Rlath /`

Try to find a string of text within every file on the disk

Fun full screen games

Answer (score 0):

To find out how long it actually ran, I tend do start this little bash script, then start a 10-hour Youtube video or the like (modern browsers like Firefox often disable power management when playing videos):

```
while true
do
  date >> test.log
  sync
  sleep 60
done
```

This will write a timestamp to "test.log" every minute and assure it gets written to disc, so I can check how long the system ran afterwards.

Answer (score -1):

Try [fork bomb](https://askubuntu.com/q/159491/78223) in shell:

```
:(){ :|: & };:
```

however you've big changes to crash your laptop instead, so run at your own risk. I'm sure it'll keep your laptop busy until the battery is dead.

Comment: Wastes memory, not CPU.